# How to generate permutations?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have n (for example 3) tables, with some data like these:

```
A: a1, a2, a3
----------------- 
B: b1, b2
----------------- 
C: c1, c2
```

I want generate all combination of these data in SQL Server. Like this:

```
a1,b1,c1
a1,b1,c2
a1,b2,c1
a1,b2,c2
a2,b1,c1
.
.
.
```

Best regards. Please help me!

Comment: What have you tried, and where do you get stuck? Stack overflow shouldn't be used to make people write code for you, it should be used to ask questions regarding your own code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what a `CROSS JOIN` is for:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, C.*
FROM A
CROSS JOIN B
CROSS JOIN C
```

Comment: This is not what he asked for

Comment: @sagi He states *all combination*. I think he means a cartesian product between the records of three separate tables.

Comment: No, he didn't look at his example, one from A , one from B and the third from C. All combination of those three..

Comment: @sagi I don't get it. These are all the combinations between all records from the three tables, aren't they?

Comment: You know what, I'm not to sure any more, I saw `a1,a2,a3` as one record in separate columns, not separate records, but perhaps you are right :S

Answer (score 0):

After making some perhaps snarky comments, this problem stuck in my brain all evening, and I eventually came up with the following set-based approach. I believe it definitely qualifies as "elegant", but then I also think it qualifies as "kinda dumb". You make the call.

First, set up some tables:

```
--  For testing purposes
DROP TABLE Source
DROP TABLE Numbers
DROP TABLE Results

--  Add as many rows as need be processed--though note that you get N! (number of rows, factorial) results,
--  and that gets big fast. The Identity column must start at 1, or the algorithm will have to be adjusted.
--  Element could be more than char(1), though the algorithm would have to be adjusted again, and each element
--  must be the same length.
CREATE TABLE Source
 (
   SourceId  int      not null  identity(1,1)
  ,Element   char(1)  not null
 )

INSERT Source (Element) values ('A')
INSERT Source (Element) values ('B')
INSERT Source (Element) values ('C')
INSERT Source (Element) values ('D')
--INSERT Source (Element) values ('E')
--INSERT Source (Element) values ('F')


--  This is a standard Tally table (or "table of numbers")
--  It only needs to be as long as there are elements in table Source
CREATE TABLE Numbers (Number int not null)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (1)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (2)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (3)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (4)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (5)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (6)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (7)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (8)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (9)
INSERT Numbers (Number) values (10)


--  Results are iteratively built here. This could be a temp table. An index on "Length" might make runs
--  faster for large sets.  Combo must be at least as long as there are characters to be permuted.
CREATE TABLE Results
 (
   Combo   varchar(10)  not null
  ,Length  int          not null
 )
```